# Nilpotent matrix generated by a polynomial formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Having non-singular matrix $A$ (real, dim. $n \times n$) we can generate singular matrix $B$ using polynomial formula $B=A-\lambda{I}$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of matrix $A$. If $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues then there are at least $n$ different  ways of generating from non-singular matrix a matrix which is singular.
If we additionally use polynomial formula based fully on the characteristic equation we can obtain, according to Cayley-Hamilton theorem, simply the zero matrix.

Nilpotency is the concept somewhere between general singularity and zero matrix.

- I'm interested whether it is possible to generate non-zero nilpotent
  matrix $B$ from non-singular matrix $A$ with the use of polynomial
  formula...

It seems that the problem is tractable when we assume that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Indeed if $B$ is generated by the polynomial formula we have
$B= A^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+ \dots+a_1A+a_0I$.

But if $A$ is diagonalizable then $A=SDS^{- 1}$ and with polynomial  formula we obtain  expression  $B=SD_2S^{-1}$ where $D_2$ is some diagonal matrix. On the other hand we require $B^k=(SD_2S^{-1})^k=0$ i.e. $(D_2)^k=0$ what is possible only when diagonal matrix  $D_2 =0$ so in this case it would be $B=SD_2S^{-1} =0$ what is in contradiction with $B$ assumed being non-zero matrix. So it seems there is no way to generate non-zero nilpotent matrix in this case.
I hope that my reasoning is correct..

However I don't know how to solve the problem if $A$ is **non-singular** **non-diagonalizable** matrix?

- Is it possible in this case to generate with the use of polynomial
  formula non-zero nilpotent matrix? What is the necessary and sufficient
  condition for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any matrix $A$ has a minimal polynomial $q(x)$ defined as the monic polynomial with minimum degree such that $q(A)=0$. An easy corollary is that

> If $p(x)$ is a polynomial, then 
>   $$p(A) =0 \iff q(x)|p(x) $$

Let now $B=p(A)$ be a non-zaero nilpotent matrix. This means that $B^k=p(A)^k=0$ and by the corollary, $q(x)|p(x)^k$ and $q(x)\not| p(x)$. This can happen if and only if $q(x)$ has irreducible factors with multiplicity at least 2. If we're working on the field of complex numbers, then we have also an useful lemma:

> The matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial is square-free

This result gives us the answer to your question:

> There exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $B=p(A)$ is a nilpotent non-zero matrix if and only if $A$ isn't diagonalizable. 
>   For example, take $p(x)$ as the product of $x-\lambda$, with $\lambda$ eigenvalues **without** multiplicity

---

Some examples:

Take the matrix 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \\
  & 1 & \\
  &   & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
this is not diagonalizable, so we take $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)$ and obtain
$$
p(A)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & \\
  & 0  & \\
  &   & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
that is nilpotent and non-zero.

The matrix must be non-diagonalizable **in $\mathbb C$**: for example take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
this is not diagonalizable in $\mathbb R$, but in $\mathbb C$ its diagonal form is
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
i & 0 \\
0 & -i 
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
and you can use your own reasoning to prove that there doesn't exist $B=p(A)$ non-zero nilpotent.

To find a real matrix  non-diagonalizable in $\mathbb R$ that is also non-diagonalizable in  $\mathbb C$, you have to reach dimension 4.
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 1 & \\
 1 & 0 &  & 1 \\
  &   & 0 & -1 \\
 & & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and in this case, the eigenvalues are $i,i,-i,-i$, so $p(x) = (x-i)(x+i) = x^2+1$. In fact,
$$
p(A)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &  &  & -2 \\
  & 0 & 2 &  \\
  &   & 0 &  \\
 & &  & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
that is non-zero nilpotent.

Comment: Hmm, this result written in the last sentence I have presented. But is it a sufficient condition to be non-diagonalizable to generate nilpotent matrix ?

Comment: yes, it is necessary and sufficient on $\mathbb C$

Comment: but on $\mathbb{R}$ ? How to find coefficients of polynomial?

Comment: well, the matrices on $\mathbb R$ are a subset of those in $\mathbb C$, so the statement is "there exists $p(x)$ such that ... if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable in $\mathbb C$"

Comment: As usual, I have some problems with these expanding fields, $\mathbb R,\mathbb  C$ it's hard for me to visualize this without a concrete example..

Comment: @Widawensen added example, and a way to find $p(x)$

Comment: Thank you E. for the examples, they shed a light on the problem..